# How to pad SQLite query results

Tags: sql, matlab, sqlite

I have a very simple SQLite database of daily price history with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE OHLCV_Components (symbol TEXT, tradeDate TEXT, openPrice REAL, highPrice REAL, lowPrice REAL, closePrice REAL, volume INTEGER)
```

Prices are in the database only for dates on which data for that symbol/date combination exist. 
I construct a query, via Matlab, to return a table of all symbols with price data for a given date range:

```
SELECT symbol, 
       tradeDate, 
       closePrice 
FROM OHLCV_Components 
WHERE tradeDate BETWEEN DATE('2000-01-01') AND DATE('2000-01-05') 
ORDER BY symbol ASC, tradeDate ASC

-------------------------------------
symbol       tradeDate     closePrice
-------------------------------------
A            2000-01-01       10.1 
A            2000-01-02       10.3 
A            2000-01-03       10.3 

B            2000-01-01        5.1 
B            2000-01-02        5.5 

C            2000-01-01       20.9 
C            2000-01-02       20.8 
C            2000-01-05       20.7 

D            2000-01-01       25.9 
D            2000-01-02       25.8 
D            2000-01-03       25.8 
D            2000-01-05       25.7
```

It is desirable for every symbol in the table to be of length equal to the longest continuous date record within the requested date range (symbol D in this case); i.e. symbols with missing price data for a given day are assigned NULL:

```
-------------------------------------
symbol      tradeDate      closePrice
-------------------------------------
A           2000-01-01        10.1 
A           2000-01-02        10.3 
A           2000-01-03        10.3
A           2000-01-05        NULL

B           2000-01-01        5.1 
B           2000-01-02        5.5 
B           2000-01-03        NULL
B           2000-01-05        NULL

C           2000-01-01        20.9 
C           2000-01-02        20.8 
C           2000-01-03        NULL
C           2000-01-05        20.7 

D           2000-01-01        25.9 
D           2000-01-02        25.8 
D           2000-01-03        25.8 
D           2000-01-05        25.7
```

Is it possible to offload this task to an efficient SQLite query, rather than addressing it programmatically, which can be painfully slow for large queries?

Comment: Your desired is not really continuous, they all miss 2000-01-04. Do you just want all dates between the minimum and the maximum in the set? With gaps, if there are any in all subsets? Or without?

Comment: The set of dates are derived from the existing data, so dates for which no transaction occurred (weekends, holidays, etc.) are not in the database. In this case, symbol D defines the longest set of continuous *valid* dates, with gaps, that each symbol should be.

Answer (score 0):

In subqueries, you can select the distinct set of trade dates and symbols in the range. Cross join them to get all the symbol trade date combinations in the range. Then left join the table to get the close price if existing.

```
SELECT y.symbol,
       x.tradedate,
       o.closeprice
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    tradedate
                    FROM ohlcv_components
                    WHERE tradedate BETWEEN date('2000-01-01')
                                            AND date('2000-01-05')) x
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                               symbol
                               FROM ohlcv_components
                               WHERE tradedate BETWEEN date('2000-01-01')
                                                       AND date('2000-01-05')) y
            LEFT JOIN ohlcv_components o
                      ON o.tradedate = x.tradedate
                         AND o.symbol = y.symbol
       ORDER BY y.symbol ASC,
                x.tradedate ASC;
```

For performance an index on `ohlcv_components(tradedate, symbol)` might be good.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!